# dynamic pricing table list

Tags: javascript, jquery

i am writing a code to select/remove the product from display table, and when the product is selected,then product with its price mus be displayed in some other table where at the end sum total is also needed which get updated as per selected product prices

```
<table id="table-example" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Cause</th>
            <th>Monthly Charge</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <div id="selectedServices"></div>
            <td id="myDiv"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table id="table-example" class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Cause</th>
            <th>Monthly Charge</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <div>
        <tbody>
            <p>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" onclick="ToggleBGColour(this);" />
                        <label>table</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>80</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" onclick="ToggleBGColour(this);" />
                        <label>chair</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>45</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" onclick="ToggleBGColour(this);" />
                        <label>set</label>
                    </td>
                    <td>10</td>
                </tr>
        </tbody>
    </div>
</table>
```

script

```
$(function() {
  $(":checkbox").change(function() {
    var arr = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function() { return $(this).next().text(); }).get();
    $("#myDiv").text(arr.join(','));
  });
});

function ToggleBGColour(item) {

    var td = $(item).parent();      

    if (td.is('.rowSelected'))      
        td.removeClass("rowSelected");      
    else        
        td.addClass("rowSelected");     

}
```

Here is the corresponding [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A2SKr/2/).

Comment: what works, what doesn't, what is your question?

Comment: i want to display selected product and its respective price in uppr table but and with totl price... how to display like

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your comment for my other answer, this should work for you then:

```
$(":checkbox").change(function () {
    // Toggle class of selected row
    $(this).parent().toggleClass("rowSelected");

    // Get all items name, sum total amount
    var sum = 0;
    var arr = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function () {
        sum += Number($(this).parents('tr').find('td:last').text());
        return $(this).parents('tr').clone();
    }).get();

    // Display selected items and their sum
    $("#selectedServices").html(arr).find('input').remove();
    $("#total").text(sum);
});
```

This avoids the need for creating new HTML elements in the JavaScript code, and reduces the number of `.maps()` and `.each()` loops to **one**.

http://jsfiddle.net/samliew/uF2Ba/

Comment: @samuel Liew:
i have updated this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/anujay/uF2Ba/9/
now i want to post the above table (upper table) value (selected data form lower table) to database but after selection no  <input> tag is coming with product name and price how to sort this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the javascript for but u need to remove onClick attrs :

```
$(function() {
  $(":checkbox").change(function() {
      ToggleBGColour(this);
      var arr = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function() { 
          return $(this).next().text(); 
      }).get();

      var nums = $(":checkbox:checked").map(function() { 
          return  parseInt($(this).parent().next().html());
      }).get();

      var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            total += nums[i] << 0;
        }


      $("#myDiv").text(arr.join(',') + 'total : '+total);

  });
});


function ToggleBGColour(item) {

    var td = $(item).parent();      

    if (td.is('.rowSelected'))      
        td.removeClass("rowSelected");      
    else        
        td.addClass("rowSelected");     

}
```

Comment: :i have updated this fiddle jsfiddle.net/anujay/uF2Ba/9 now i want to post the above table (upper table) value (selected data form lower table) to database but after selection no <input> tag is coming with product name and price how to sort this?

Answer (score 0):

I updated your fiddle with my answer : http://jsfiddle.net/A2SKr/9/

Here's what i've changed.

- Slightly better formatted.
- i removed the `onclick` attribute. Its bad practice to use this because of performance issues. Use delegates
- Ive also changed a lil bit of your HTML. the output is now a table
- added a total element to the output as well
- javascript code :

  ```
  $(":checkbox").change(function () {
       var total = 0;
       var check = $(":checkbox:checked");
       var causes = check.map(function () {
           return $(this).next().text();
       }).get();
       var costs = check.map(function () {
           return $(this).parent().next().text()
       }).get();
       var tbody = $("#table-example tbody").empty();
       $.each(causes, function (i, cause) {
           tbody.append("<tr><td>" + cause + "</td><td id='" + i + "'><td/></tr>");
       });
       $.each(costs, function (i, cost) {
           $('#' + i + '').html(cost);
           total += parseInt(cost, 10);
       });
       tbody.append("<tr><td>Total</td><td>" + total + "<td/></tr>");
   });
  });
  ```

Comment: :i have updated this fiddle jsfiddle.net/anujay/uF2Ba/9 now i want to post the above table (upper table) value (selected data form lower table) to database but after selection no <input> tag is coming with product name and price how to sort this?

Comment: @user2325244 i dont think you can do that!! you're not searching for `<input>` tags anymore if youre trying to take the selected data from the table on top! here's an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/uF2Ba/11/.. added a click handler and a button and printing out the values to console

Comment: @passionteCoder is upper table(dynmic one) sort of form??

Comment: No its not. Its not a form. Its a table,

Comment: yaa that i got... but i want to submit the above table valu to database and for that this table should b treated under form tag... i applied the form tab to it... but on submit the output it nothing because no input field coming to the above table <td>.. did u got what i want to ask for?

Comment: check your app in console in lower table you'll find this in console ::
<td class="rowSelected">
<input type="checkbox" value="table" name="product[]">


<label>table</label>
</td>

i want input tag in upper table <td> also so that i my post the selected value

Comment: Add a hidden <input > tag and stash the values to it.that's all u can do